# How do I create a bare repo clone of existing git working repo

Tags: git, git-bare

I have been sole developer, working on a project with a local repository under git.

Now I need to create a bare repo for collaboration on a local network.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git clone -l --bare old_repo_dir new_repo.git
```

---

Note: if the plan is to collaborate over the web, it might be better to simply create a web-hosted repo and push the local one to that.